# How to add a row to a Table View controller (with data from a textfield) when a button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making an app that is using core data, and I have 2 textfields and a button saying "save data".So I want when the button is pressed the data from the textfields is displayed on a new row in a table view controller.In Xcode using Objective C.

Image of views - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UrMO.png

Thanks
Beginner to programming

Comment: Are you Used tableviewdelegate methods?

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Update your model (used to draw your cell) with textFields text. Something like this:

```
[self.items addObject:<Object_With_Both_TextFields_Text>]
```

**Step 2:** On button tap, insert a new row like this:

```
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Where do I enter this code in the view controller or table view controller and where in those files ( .h or .m).

Comment: This should go in .m of your 'UITableViewControler' delegate class.

Comment: Could you please throw more light on how your views are laid down. Because the kind of questions you are asking is really confusing me. I suggested an approach to you thinking you could follow it. But if you are looking answer for specific questions, you would need to update your question with more details including code on how your views are laid down. I was expecting you had one view controller with top having text fields and bottom having table view in which case your text fields are managed by same view controller.

Comment: Sorry for my vague question,I have added a picture of my view controllers in the original question.I want the "Name" and "Age" input to be displayed in a new row on the table view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the **new data from text fields to your table view data source** (mostly this will be a mutable array or dictionary). Then call reloadData on your table view.

1. Add the entry from text fields into your table view data source.

   ```
   [yourMutableArray addObject:[textField1 text]];
   ```
2. call `[yourTableView reloadData];`

Comment: As per my opinion its not good idea to reload whole  tableview while inserting new row its better to use its DataSource inserRowAtIndexpath:

Comment: Is not the best solution but it works very well. There is not only one solution. Normally I use this way and never problems.

Comment: @PiyushPatel: While I agree with your point, there's no harm in "Reloading the table view" in case of small updates. And in this question, Muhammed Mafawalla asked about loading contents from two text fields, which I feel is minor updates. Hope I make sense!!

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick : Yes you are right, I am agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

When you press 'save data', add content that you want to display into the `your_array` that you are using to display the `tableview`.

```
[your_array addObject:your_textfield_string];
```

After that reload the table again using `[tableview reloadData]`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [tableview reloadData];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    ////TO SCROLL THE TABLE TO NEWLY ADDED ROW
                    int lastRowNumber = [tableview numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;

                    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
                    [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
                });

            });
```